# Android webview

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello Everyone 
I an using webview in my android app . The problem i am facing that i want to remove the scroll bar white color because i an using black color as a body bgcolor . So in simple words hw we can remove scrolling or scroll bar  in the android web view . 
Thanks

Comment: I have found the solution appView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.appView);
 
Beneath that, add these two lines:
 
appView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
appView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you have found a solution, there is another way though.  You can also set the attribute in your xml layout file.  `android:scrollbars="none"`